# AngularJS detect button id

Tags: angularjs

I have several buttons,which's id is given by data that I ajax,and every id is different.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary likes" id="{{data.id}}" role="button" ng-click="likes()">XXX</a>
```

How do I detect a button's id when it is clicked?

Comment: I suggest you to read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the id to the likes function:

```
ng-click='likes(data.id)'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

```
data-ng-click='likes(data.id)'
```

or if you want pass the index of element

```
data-ng-click='likes($index)'
```